# Логи ошибок Flurry

Tags: android

Установил в свое приложение Flurry для ведения статистики, в его логах содержиться примерно 40 таких ошибок:

> class android.util.AndroidRuntimeException
> Msg: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature:285 (requestFeature() must be called before adding content)

Вопрос, что за ошибка, чем вызвана?

Answer (score 3):

В тексте исключения написано. `requestFeature()` нужно вызывать до того, как будет вызван метод `setContentView()`.

**Upd:** возможно `FlurryAgent` вызывает этот метод, попробуйте переставить вызов `onStartSession()` так, чтобы он был перед `setContentView()`.

Comment: мм?
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "FJTSD3JUNCPVN1UZHDPE");

Comment: Это всё что есть в onCreate()? т.е. вы не вызываете requestFeature() в явном виде?

Comment: Да. Нет.

Comment: Попробуйте вызывать.

Comment: Вряд ли вызов что-то даст. Посмотрите апдейт ответа.